# Simplest way to post-process the result of a jQuery ajax request?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Suppose I have a function `fancyParse` intended to take the response returned by the server and turn it into something else. This function throws if the response makes no sense whatsoever, or if it has a special "internal error" flag set.

I'd like to chain this function into a `$.post` call to get a new `Deferred`. This new deferred would fail if the request fails, or if `fancyParse` throws. It would succeed if the request succeeds and `fancyParse` succeeds, and, importantly, will pass the result of `fancyParse` to its success callbacks.

The perfect solution would look something like this:

```js
$.post('/url', etc).postprocess(fancyParse)
    .done(my_done_handler)
    .fail(my_fail_handler);
```

Is something like this already available, or do I need to write such a `postprocess` myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dataFilter` function can be used to process data. You pass it with your request.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    ...,
    dataFilter: function (data, type) {
        // do something with data and return it
        return data.toLowerCase();
    }
})
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't state this, but perhaps you know: do exceptions in the filter function cause the request to be treated as failed?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. But why don't you catch exceptions and then call the error handler from within your post-processor?

Comment: Because there's more to it than calling the error handler. I need the `Deferred` to become *rejected*, too, so that any error handlers added afterwards are also invoked.

Comment: Confirmed: if this throws, the fail handlers are invoked, as expected. This is certainly the simplest way of achieving what I want.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with this as it relates to piping the result.  If you add a dataFilter, the next deferred object is passed no arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You can create you own deferred object:

```
$.postProcess = function(addr,test) {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();         // create deferred object
  $.post(addr)                    // make ajax call
  .success( function(response) {  // if ajax is OK
    if (test) {                   // Your filter test
      dfd.resolve("OK");          // if test is passed, call done()
    } else {
      dfd.reject("Bad test");     // otherwise call reject
    }
  })
  .error(function() {             // on ajax error
   dfd.reject("Error");           // reject
  });
  return dfd.promise();                     // return deferred object
};

//$.postProcess('/echo/json/',true)   // to test good case
//$.postProcess('/echo/json/',false)  // to test bad test
$.postProcess('/echo/error/',true)    // to test bad ajax
.done( function(msg){
    alert('ok:'+msg);
})
.fail( function(msg){
    alert('fail:'+msg);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bouillard/FRsjV/

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I've +1'd this. I think I'll use this for something else I have in mind, but for the postprocess thing the `dataFilter` is perfect.

Comment: Yes, on this case, datafilter should be shorter than deferred. But deferred could be a very convenient way for some application. Thx.